# Restlet: how to suppress server request log messages

Tags: logging, restlet

I have created a simple REST server using Restlet 2.1.2 and it is working very well. Every POST or GET request causes Restlet to emit a log message of the form:

```
2013-05-02  19:44:39    127.0.0.1   -   -   8081    POST    /rest/dispatch  -   200 -   -   21  http://127.0.0.1:8081Restlet-Framework/2.1.2    -
```

There are a lot of requests and it is not important for the application to collect those messages. Questions:

- From what class is that message emitted? I have tried to grep through the Restlet source code to find it, but no luck.
- Those messages are being sent to stdout. How can I write them directly to a file?
- How can I configure it so that such messages are generated only if the response status is something other than 200 ?

Thanks a lot for any information.

PS: I found some links which seem relevant, although I haven't yet puzzled out exactly what needs to be done. I'll leave these here for future reference.

- http://restlet.org/learn/tutorial/2.1/#part07
- http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.1/editions/jse/logging
- http://restlet.org/learn/guide/2.0/core/service/log
- http://restlet.org/learn/javadocs/snapshot/jse/engine/org/restlet/engine/log/LogFilter.html
- http://restlet-discuss.1400322.n2.nabble.com/Hiding-Restlet-LogFilter-afterHandler-log-td7578429.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create and set a NullLogService that says all requests are not loggable:

```
public class NullLogService extends LogService 
{
    @Override
    public boolean isLoggable(Request request) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and then set that as your log service:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
    Component component = new Component();
    component.getServers().add(Protocol.HTTP, 8082);

    Application application = new RestletTestResource();  

    component.getDefaultHost().attach(application);  
    component.setLogService(new NullLogService());
    component.start();    
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million! About logging only responses which have HTTP return code other than 200, I suppose I could extract that from the argument of `isLoggable` ?

Comment: seems like it would be a decent way to do it